# How do I remove the rest of a string after a character in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains userdata. There is a column that includes filenames that users have accessed. The filenames look like this:

```
blah-blah-blah/dss_outline.pdf  
doot-doot/helper_doc.pdf
blah-blah-blah/help_file.pdf
```

My goal is to chop off everything after and including the / so that I can just look at the top-level programs people are examining (which the numerous different files are organized under).

So, I'm having two challenges:

1 - How do I 'grab' everything up to the '/'? I've been looking at regex, but I'm having a hard time writing the correct expression.

2 - How do I replace all of the filenames with the concatenated filename? I found that I could use `df['Filename'] = df['Filename'].str.split('/')[0]` to grab the proper portion, but it won't apply across the series object. That's the logic of what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: "but it won't apply across the series object" meaning? can you please explain any further. :)

Comment: `df['your_column_name'] = df['your_column_name'].map(lambda a: os.path.basename(a))` Depending on your folder structure, as suggested below you could use `str.split()` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lot of solutions handy:

### 1) Just with `split()` method:

```
>>> df
                             col1
0  blah-blah-blah/dss_outline.pdf
1        doot-doot/helper_doc.pdf
2    blah-blah-blah/help_file.pdf


>>> df['col1'].str.split('/', 1).str[0].str.strip()
0    blah-blah-blah
1         doot-doot
2    blah-blah-blah
```

Name: col1, dtype: object

### 2) You can use `apply()` + `split()`

```
>>> df['col1'].apply(lambda s: s.split('/')[0])
0    blah-blah-blah
1         doot-doot
2    blah-blah-blah
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

### 3) You can use `rsplit()` + `str[0]` to strip off the desired:

```
>>> df['col1'].str.rsplit('/').str[0]
0    blah-blah-blah
1         doot-doot
2    blah-blah-blah
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

### 4) You can use pandas native regex With `extract()`:

```
>>> df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract('([^/]+)')
>>> df
             col1
0  blah-blah-blah
1       doot-doot
2  blah-blah-blah

OR
# df.col1.str.extract('([^/]+)')
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you for sharing the numerous options here! I'm still getting up to speed on pandas/regex/lambda expressions so it's nice to see them all represented here.

Comment: @RNGeezy, thnx for liking and accepting this as an answer, happy learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `\/.*$` to match the part you don't need and remove it: [DEMO](https://regexr.com/47a40)
This matches a forward slash and any following character till the end of the string (be careful to use a multiline flag if your engine needs it!).

OR you may use `^[^/]+` to match the part you want and extract it: [DEMO](https://regexr.com/47a46)
This matches any consecutive characters except `/` from the beginning of a string (again, multiline needed!).

Comment: How do I apply that across the column in the dataframe? So, say I used re.sub() to replace the unwanted bits with an empty string, how do I apply that row by row?

Comment: You will have to iterate over the rows and apply it one by one, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.replace`

```
df.replace('\/.*$','',regex=True)


              col
0  blah-blah-blah
1       doot-doot
2  blah-blah-blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `series.apply()`:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> data = {'filename': ["blah-blah-blah/dss_outline.pdf", "doot-doot/helper_doc.pdf", "blah-blah-blah/help_file.pdf"]}
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> df
                         filename
0  blah-blah-blah/dss_outline.pdf
1        doot-doot/helper_doc.pdf
2    blah-blah-blah/help_file.pdf
>>> def get_top_level_from(string):
...     return string.split('/')[0]
... 
>>> series = df["filename"]
>>> series
0    blah-blah-blah/dss_outline.pdf
1          doot-doot/helper_doc.pdf
2      blah-blah-blah/help_file.pdf
Name: filename, dtype: object
>>> series.apply(get_top_level_from)
0    blah-blah-blah
1         doot-doot
2    blah-blah-blah
Name: filename, dtype: object
```

Code:

```
def get_top_level_from(string):
    return string.split('/')[0]

results = df["filename"].apply(get_top_level_from)
```